# Raspberry Pi 4B... Issues with docker not running because of aufs

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, installation, driver, raspberry-pi4

To begin with I bought a raspberry pi 4b. I installed berry boot on the sd and connected a SSD 480gb. I managed to get it working with a Tv as a monitor hdmi group = 1 etc.

I then set up ssh with macbook so I can access my pi with my labtop or use the desktop raspbian.

Followed a 4 month old youtube video (relatively new).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx-Hfq5Hc6E

I used the commands as follows:

```
//install docker

#curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ |sh

//Set up so root isn't used as user - recommended

#sudo usermod -aG docker pi

//https://hub.docker.com/r/michaelmiklis/rpi-monitor (last updated 2 years ago)...
//used quick start command for project (this worked for the video just 4 months ago)

#docker run --device=/dev/vchiq --device=/dev/vcsm --volume=/opt/vc:/opt/vc --volume=/boot:/boot --volume=/sys:/dockerhost/sys:ro --volume=/etc:/dockerhost/etc:ro --volume=/proc:/dockerhost/proc:ro --volume=/usr/lib:/dockerhost/usr/lib:ro -p=8888:8888 --name="rpi-monitor" -d  michaelmiklis/rpi-monitor:latest
```

this command produces an error response:

```
#docker: Error response from daemon: error creating aufs mount to /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/b46dae086de8d3cf89a07e9079fb311d3989768f482418fbfdcf3c886aa5f516-init: mount target=/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/b46dae086de8d3cf89a07e9079fb311d3989768f482418fbfdcf3c886aa5f516-init data=br:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/b46dae086de8d3cf89a07e9079fb311d3989768f482418fbfdcf3c886aa5f516-init=rw:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/987d36feb1d5eda275ebd7191449f82db9921b8ea21d9f4d1089529b5bdcf30f=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/19ff179d7ce8587e1174b2cbba701a46910d7a5a4dbc62e9c58498cff5eb9bba=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/13be75a7cabe4da1b971b1fb8b25b6bc6fdb6ab13456790dfc25da23e97b9aa0=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/8b2d2a79ba8e0f4235d3ce623f6cda8486f7293af60abe24623f9fd70b2f7613=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/776dcea3b43ecd880a459ec7182305eea7d9779dab0fe45b69d3558a5401fc7b=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/a3f67653f5d5507a1ca3a4627563bd916be979ae1593dda8d0073f1f152b01a3=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/3176f9f6ed8047e376bacf9ee42370158329d66a8cfe7afd7e1a4d65d5022698=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/7427fa9add426dee44acf434935d13c6fddaac36ad222b12037b8a0a8529c222=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/27ffbeb11ca61262f65d85dfd748190b9b64223112e7faaf5f7f69eb47ada066=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/6781db1c1025f9d601bb0c4dd54df180c8fbda8d0632cc77835574b74a3f7179=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/1fa0fdfb5625eb000d3f6424b84dd8d9c19fb3ce721789277a72f2588f547659=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/a3da4ba9bfe80df4efc955929d4fa0b63d0dbf922b483f9d582507adf38e0192=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/b027240667462a4ff2e540b0cbdbbd78fdf3000c1ecdae734efc0ef794bc90f0=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/7aea6d1beaa5a57f1eac445759c1acfa563b9a8c87ce592d61797caa92547f38=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/e3ff1cda15a224b9c3af5a1a772f3373635abd031c9a4546f157b4550b7df245=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/e751ee6e4e942642958f1d9459e5b707d3970b53d70e5ae1986a70cbd2973435=ro+wh,dio,xino=/dev/shm/aufs.xino: invalid argument.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I have read about the my issue except in regards to the raspberry pi and haven't been able to workout a solution please help!

BTW I have tried uninstalling docker and installing it again (sudo apt remove docker-ce). If it is a driver issue I don't know how to tell docker to not use aufs but to only use ?"overlay2"?
Remember my pi boots from sd but runs raspbian os on my ssd (there might be an issue there with docker maybe). I very much appreciate any help.

Comment: I ended up scrapping this because in the end I got some advice saying that the berryboot kernel isn't compatible with docker.